# Numerical Evaluation of Pi

Tags: c

I would like to evaluate Pi approximately by running the following code which fits a regular polygon of n sides inside a circle with unit diameter and calculates its perimeter using the function in the code. However the output after the 34th term is 0 when long double variable type is used or it increases without bounds when double variable type is used. How can I remedy this situation? Any suggestion or help is appreciated and welcome.

Thanks

P.S: Operating system: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit, Compiler: GCC 4.6.3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define increment 0.25
int main()
{
    int i = 0, k = 0, n[6] = {3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96};
    double per[61] = {0}, per2[6] = {0};

    // Since the above algorithm is recursive we need to specify the perimeter for n = 3;
    per[3] = 0.5 * 3 * sqrtl(3);
    for(i = 3; i <= 60; i++)
    {
        per[i + 1] = powl(2, i) * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl(1.0 - (per[i] / powl(2, i)) * (per[i] / powl(2, i)))));
        printf("%d      %f \n", i, per[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    {
        //p[k] = k
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting 1.0 from a nearly-1.0 number is leading to "catastrophic cancellation", where the relative error in a FP calculation skyrockets due to the loss of significant digits. Try evaluating `pow(2, i) - (pow(2, i) - 1.0)` for each i between 0 and 60 and you'll see what I mean.

The only real solution to this issue is reorganizing your equations to avoid subtracting nearly-equal nonzero quantities. For more details, see Acton, *Real Computing Made Real*, or Higham, *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms*.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. I think the instructor have had us do it this way on purpose, that is he wants us to be aware of these facts. As far as I am concerned you are proposing that the accuracy cannot be increased and other terms cannot be calculated although the machine epsilon is lower for long double.

Comment: Long double buys you a few more iterations, and rearranging your terms can help too (sometimes it can help a LOT), but there's just way too many problems with this method of approximation, and you run out of bits surprisingly quickly. IMHO, any iterative approximation is "guilty until proven innocent" -- writing really robust and accurate FP algorithms like this is a difficult problem, and error control needs to be dealt with from step one.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

Use `y = (1.0 - x)*( 1.0 + x)` instead of `y = 1.0 - x*x`.  This helps with 1 stage of "subtraction of nearly equal values", but I am still stuck on the next `1.0 - sqrtl(y)` as `y` approaches 1.0.

```
// per[i + 1] = powl(2, i) * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl(1.0 - (per[i] / powl(2, i)) * (per[i] / powl(2, i)))));
long double p = powl(2, i);
// per[i + 1] = p * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl(1.0 - (per[i] / p) * (per[i] / p))));
long double x = per[i] / p;
// per[i + 1] = p * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl(1.0 - x * x)));
// per[i + 1] = p * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl((1.0 - x)*(1.0 + x)) ));
long double y = (1.0 - x)*( 1.0 + x);
per[i + 1] = p * sqrtl(2 * (1.0 - sqrtl(y) ));
```

Change array size or `for()`

```
double per[61+1] = { 0 };  // Add 1 here
...
for (i = 3; i <= 60; i++) {
  ...
  per[i + 1] =
```

---

Following is a similar method for pi

```
unsigned n = 6;
double sine = 0.5;
double cosine = sqrt(0.75);
double pi = n*sine;
static const double mpi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
do {
  sine = sqrt((1 - cosine)/2);
  cosine = sqrt((1 + cosine)/2);
  n *= 2;
  pi = n*sine;
  printf("%6u s:%.17e c:%.17e  pi:%.17e %%:%.6e\n", n, sine, cosine, pi, (pi-mpi)/mpi);
} while (n <500000);
```

Comment: @Vesnog  Do you have a reference for your recursive equation?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately I have no reference for my recursive equation it might be from a textbook involving numerical calculations. I will try your recommendation after I am done with another task.

Comment: @Vesnog BTW: `per[i>17]` converges to `2.64605984256397475`.  It this expected?  The subtraction problems occur about 4 terms later, so maybe term calculation may stop early.  Further, there is an "unusualness" to this equation that I have not sort out yet.